# Blog on Google App Engine for Java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am considering to add a Blog on my GAE/J application and wondered what is the best way to do so.

Are there any implementations I can use?

Should I write something on my own?

I read about Microblog but it is written in python, I am not sure it will co-exists with my Java app.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know any implementations that you can use, this question is very broad and there are a lot of different things that you could do, and writing your own is one of them.

Just to begin with you could use the [Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/) to read the posts and present them in your app. By doing that you're able to add/modify/delete posts using the Blogger's UI and in your own app you will only present the posts. The only problem with this solution is regarding the comments, where you could implement your own (just to start somewhere) or include maybe the Facebook's [Comments Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).

I did exactly that for the [kiebdoj.com/blog/](http://www.kiebdoj.com/blog/) and it saved me a lot of time for not implementing my own [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor or a post manager. That was written in Python, so I can't provide any examples, but in either case it wasn't written to work on it's own.